# How do i correctly prevent orphans and widows with nowidow?

Tags: widows-orphans

With the `nowidow` packet, orphans and widows are apparently prevented.

Is it enough to add `\usepackage[all]{nowidow}` in the preamble, or does the command `defaultlines` also have to be inserted in square brackets?

Comment: if you want to avoid orphans and widows you might want to look at the `widows-and-orphans` package which is a semi-automatic solution but generally gives better results than using tex parameters to forbid widows.

Comment: The console shows me a warning that there is an orphan on page 3. Does it mean that I have to correct it myself?

Comment: yes see the package documentation. That's why the results are better, if you simply prevent orphans/widows then tex has no good way to resolve it it has to keep the linebreaking the same and break the page one line short or long to avoid the orphaned line, but usually you can adjust the line breaking with eg `\looseness=-1` so the paragraph is broken into one less line so fits on the page without leaving a trailing line, or you can adjust the text or ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just notice that the console is falsely giving me this warning, even though it is actually not an orphan…